# How to use memoryview on Python 3 strings?

Tags: string, python-3.x, memoryview

In Python 3, executing:

```
memoryview("this is a string")
```

produces the error:

```
TypeError: memoryview: str object does not have the buffer interface
```

What should I do in order to make `memoryview` accept strings or what transformation should I do to my strings in order to be accepted by `memoryview`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#memoryview), `memoryview` works only over objects which support the `bytes` or `bytearray` interface. (These are similar types except the former is read-only.)

Strings in Python 3 are not raw byte buffers we can directly manipulate, rather they are [immutable sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq) of Unicode runes or characters. A `str` can be converted to a buffer, though, by *encoding* it with any of the supported [string encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) like 'utf-8', 'ascii', etc.

```
memoryview(bytes("This is a string", encoding='utf-8'))
```

Note that the `bytes()` call necessarily involves converting and copying the string data into a new buffer accessible to `memoryview`. As should be evident from the preceding paragraph, is not possible to directly create a `memoryview` over the `str`'s data.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that the error already provides clarity on the issue and [camflint's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54449407/1356062), I'll only add that you could succinctly create a `memoryview` instance from a string as follows:

```
memoryview( b"this is a string" )
```